# Image Net Preprocessing using torch transforms

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, image-preprocessing, imagenet

I am trying to recreate the data preprocessing on the ImageNet data set done in the original publication ["Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385). As said in their paper in section 3.4:
"Our implementation for ImageNet follows the practice in [21, 41].  The image is resized with its shorter side randomly sampled in[256,480]for scale augmentation [41].A 224×224 crop is randomly sampled from an image or its horizontal flip, with the per-pixel mean subtracted [21]. The standard color augmentation in [21] is used."

I have figured out the parts of randomly cropping the original image or the horizontal flip with a crop size of 224x224. The other two parts I have not. The other two parts are *The image is resized with its shorter side randomly sampled in[256,480] for scale augmentation* and the *The standard color augmentation in [21] is used.*

For the first one, I can't find a "random resize" function in torch transforms. The second, where its referencing [21], is (according to [21]) a "perform  PCA  on  the  set  of  RGB  pixel  values  throughout  theImageNet training set". Please refer to [ImageNet Classification with Deep Convolutional Neural Networks](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2012/file/c399862d3b9d6b76c8436e924a68c45b-Paper.pdf) in section "Data Augmentation" for the full explanation.

How would I recreate this type of preprocessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one needs 3 combined transforms, `RandomChoice`, `Resize` and `RandomCrop`.

```
transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomChoice([transforms.Resize(256), 
                                             transforms.Resize(480)]),
                    transforms.RandomCrop(224)
                    ])
```

For the second one [this](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations/blob/master/albumentations/augmentations/transforms.py#L2466) is what you're looking for but officially Pytorch (and literally everybody else) simply uses this.

```
transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
```

If you think that's too simple, the [standard Tensorflow pre-processing](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L192) is just

```
x /= 127.5
x -= 1.
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you. :)